# CRecordset fails on adding a new row using the free ODBC driver for SQLite

Tags: c++, sqlite, mfc, odbc, crecordset

I have an C++ application using MFC `CRecordset` to add rows to a table of an SQLite database, using the [free ODBC driver by Ch. Werner](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/). For this, I use the usual sequence of `rs.Open()`, `rs.AddNew()`, set values, and finally `rs.Update()`.

This works on a small example, but with my actual database `rs.Update()` fails with error -1 and the following error message: `unrecognized token: ""RedFaktorFly" (1)`. The 'token' is a truncated name of column 14 of the table, whose full name is "RedFaktorFlyt".
In some runs, it appends seemingly random characters, so the message becomes for ex. `unrecognized token: ""RedFaktorFlyH" (1)`.

Interestingly, when I add "LongNames=true" to the ODBC connection string, which prepends table names to the column names and therefore makes the SQL query longer, the error becomes (for ex.) `unrecognized token: ""K_Noder.MaxKompresjox" (1)` - where "MaxKompresjonsFaktor" is the name of column 10 of the table.

This seems to suggest that there is a limit on the length of a SQL query accepted by the driver - but it seems strange that such a limit would be so small that it would fail already with 14 columns.

I do not think that the limit is in the C++ part, since the same code works fine both with the (commercial) SQLite driver from Devart and with Microsoft's ODBC driver for Access.

I tried adding a `TraceFile` option to the ODBC connection string, but it does not seem to do anything, so I do not know what exactly gets sent to the ODBC driver.

I see the same behaviour both with 32- and 64-bit builds, using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Any suggestions what to try next?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the driver, failing to properly handle strings. `mktypeinfo` looks somewhat fishy, though you would probably be best off debugging into the driver code to find out where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a solution to solve your issue completely. I don't know if it's suitable for you, but definitely it works. I successfully use it on my own.

For any operation except listing records, use `CDatabase`, not `CRecordset`. So, to insert rows to any table, to update records, to delete records, use `CDatabase`. To retrieve records from SQLLite database, use `CRecordset`. I can give you examples if you need.

Comment: This could work for one table, but the code has ca. 30 tables, so this would require rewriting (and testing) potentially several thousands line of code. It is much easier to pay for the Devart driver - but I want to understand what is going with the free driver...

Comment: Understood. Fair enough.